# wxWidgets: How to refer to child components?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a wxPanel named p.

I have 5 textboxes on it.

How do I assign a static piece of text to each text box within the panel without doing it one by one? Can I refer to them like referring to array elements?

Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a666cfe7cc8eda6fcecfd39c67c50f609

Answer (score 2):

an example would may look like this:

```
for( wxWindowList::iterator it = yourWindow->GetChildren().begin();
     it != yourWindow->GetChildren().end(); it++){

     wxStaticText* aStaticText = dynamic_cast<wxStaticText *>( *it );

    if( aStaticText ){
     aStaticText->SetLabel( wxT("FooBar") );
    }

}
```

i did not test/compile it, so please excuse any typos

Comment: this is a pretty clever technique... Could you please explain what the line `wxStaticText* aStaticText = dynamic_cast<wxStaticText *>( *it );` does? Thanks! Perhaps some comments would do.

Comment: ok i will try to break this down, step by step `it` is an iterator to a list containing `wxWindow *` pointers so `*it` will give you a 'wxWindow *' pointer. Since you want to access a feature o a specific wxWindow subclass, in your case wxStaticText(?), you need a cast. The dynamic i put there is just more convenient than a `static_cast` or a c-like cast since it will also work when your window/panel contains elements of a different type

Answer (score 1):

since `wxPanel` is a subclass of `wxWindow` you could use [`wxWindow::GetChildren`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxwindow.html#wxwindowgetchildren)

this will get you a stl-like list of all children

Comment: Yes, I noticed that method. However, I'm not quite sure how to use it. Would you be able to show me an example of how you'd set the value of the second textbox in the panel? Thanks!